# How to get global variables definition from symbols tables?

Tags: c, visual-studio, data-structures, global, symbol-table

I am doing development with Visual Studio 2005 or 2010 in C/C++ language. I want to get a global structure definition information from symbol tables in a binary or execute file. Take a example in the following. A global structure named 'TD' and three members in the structure. After the code is compiled, the information will be in the symbols tables, PDB symbol file or DBG file. Are there any set of function to abstract the info from symbols table? Can I get the size of a member and the type of this member?

```
typedef struct {
void * pointer;
int    b;
char c;
}TD;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [ISymbolReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.symbolstore.isymbolreader%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) interface. I have the C# example here:

```
        // Create the Metadata dispenser.
        IMetaDataDispenserEx pDispenser = new IMetaDataDispenserEx();

        // Open the Metadata importer for the given file.
        Guid importerIID = new Guid(RCWHelper.IID_IMetaDataImport);
        IntPtr pImporter = IntPtr.Zero;
        pDispenser.OpenScope(filepath, COR_OPEN_FLAGS.ofRead, ref importerIID, out pImporter);

        SymBinder binder = new SymBinder();
        ISymbolReader symReader = binder.GetReader(pImporter, filepath);
```

Then, you can use GetGlobalVariables and GetVariables methods of this interface to get a full information on your variables.